# Split Item into N Item based on the value of a property

Tags: c#, linq

Split Item in N Item based on the value of a property.

#### Problem:

We have a `List<Movie>`. A `Movie` has Genres in this format `Genre="1;2;3"`
We split a movie into N movie, with n the number of Genre.

Instead of a list of movie where each movie has multiple genre.
We would like to have a list of movie where each movie have only one genre.

```
Movie{Genre="1;2;3",Title="3 Time" }
=> 
Movie{Genre="1",Title="3 Time" },
Movie{Genre="2",Title="3 Time" },
Movie{Genre="3",Title="3 Time" }
```

#### MRE:

```
    var separator = ";".ToCharArray();
    var inputs = new[]{
        new Movie{Genre="1;2;3",Title="3 Time" },
        new Movie{Genre="1;2",Title="Twice" },
        new Movie{Genre="1",Title="Once" }
    };
    
    var expectedResult = new[]{
        new Movie{Genre="1",Title="3 Time" },
        new Movie{Genre="2",Title="3 Time" },
        new Movie{Genre="3",Title="3 Time" },

        new Movie{Genre="1",Title="Twice" },
        new Movie{Genre="2",Title="Twice" },

        new Movie{Genre="1",Title="Once" }
    };
    
    var results = new List<Movie> { };
    foreach (var item in inputs)
    {
        foreach (var subGenre in item.Genre.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            results.Add(new Movie { Genre = subGenre, Title = item.Title });
        }
    }
    
    var valid = results.SequenceEqual(expectedResult);
    
    
    public partial class Movie 
    {
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
    
    //For Unit Testing and Sequence Equal. Not need for reproduction
    public partial class Movie : IEquatable<Movie>
    {
        public bool Equals(Movie movie)
        {
            if (movie is null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return this.Genre == movie.Genre && this.Title == movie.Title;

        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Movie);
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (Title, Genre).GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Movie i1, Movie i2)
        {
            return i1.Equals(i2);
        }
        public static bool operator !=(Movie i1, Movie i2)
        {
            return !(i1.Equals(i2));
        }

    }
```

Is there a LinQ way to do the double foreach treatment?

If the string as list feels unnatural here is a version where Genre is an array:

```
inputs.Select(x =>
    new
    {
        splittedProperty = x.Genre.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray(),
        x.Title
    });
```

Comment: SelectMany() is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be done by using [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) LINQ method:

```
var movies = inputs.SelectMany(
    m => m.Genre.Split(new[] {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(g => new Movie(g, m.Title))
);
```

I've added another constructor into `Movie` class, but you can use class initializer instead as well:

```
public partial class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {

    }

    public Movie(string genre, string title)
    {
        Genre = genre;
        Title = title;
    }

    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```